# Is there a way to create a widget for monitoring soap operations in AWS CloudWatch to count http statuses?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to create widget for monitoring purposes, which will group status codes for each soap operation.
I have logs with message statuses like:

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
```

or

```
"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"
```

And logs with requests containing operation body. The only common information binding logs with http statuses and soap body is @IngestionTime. As far as I know nested queries in Logs Insight are not allowed.
Is there any way to create widget for each operation, which will make statistics like:

```
status | count
---------------
200    |   1
400    |   3
```

Is there any way to do that?

- I tried to add MDC field, but it is not visible in Logs Insights
- Create nested query (I think it is not possible)
- Create end logger with operation name and status (unsuccessfull)